# Fade working on FF but not on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

This is my site: http://noamsm.co.il

It should fade-in some text when the search box gets focus. and fade-out on blur.

But it isn't working.

You can view source; I put the jquery code in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IE i get the javascript exceptions "google is undefined" and "jquery is undefined".
I think in IE, the "google" reference fails which in turn aborts the script and such that the jquery reference also fails. So i would start by figuring out why the Google reference is failing in IE.

Here is an SO link, not sure if it applies to you:

[Google is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657555/google-is-undefined)

Comment: i ended by having jquery on my server. and it fixed the issue :) thx

Answer (score 1):

Instead of $(document).Ready you should use

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
  jQuery(function($) {
    // run your jQuery code in here after DOM has loaded
  });
});
```

This is becuase the jQuery takes time to load dynamically using google.Load();

You could replace the script to load the google library and the call to google.Load with the direct link to jQuery below carry on using $(document).Ready

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```